# Medical procedure to sever the brain's ability to communicate with the heart?

Tags: brain, surgery, prevention, heart

So, I think I read some-where that there is a surgical procedure to server the heart's ability to communicate with the brain, for reasons. A negative consequence of this was not being able to, for example, know if you're having a heart attack.

Know what I mean?
Edit: I'm asking for the name of the procedure.

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the term you're looking for is *cardiac sympathetic denervation* (CSD). [This](https://www.news-medical.net/news/20111220/Cutting-cardiac-sympathetic-nerve-may-help-control-heart-rhythms.aspx) is a fairly non-technical explanation of the procedure. It can be left side only (LCSD), right side only (RCSD), or bilateral (BCSD). In short, it's a procedure of last resort to control ventricular arrhythmias when drugs and endocardial ablation procedures have failed.

Comment: Would you mind expanding this answer why this is the case? Because AFAIK, they cut the nerves to to the heart (the ganglion of the symphaticus, part of the ANS mostly „sends“ to the heart), not the other way round?

Comment: @Narusan Did you read the link? It's pretty specific about which nerves are cut. "`To help control arrhythmias, surgeons snip the stellate ganglion, as well as the following three ganglia below it to completely remove these nerves that are destined for the heart.`"

Comment: I think Narusan is referencing the OP's mention of not being able to detect a heart attack, which doesn't really make much sense anyways because of the way pain from the heart is sensed, but I think your answer could expand a bit on that relative to the OP's question. Also it's best to include your answer in your answer rather than support it with links that are likely to die in the future.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think I addressed the OP's question adequately in that all it really asks for is the name of the procedure. That's why I didn't include more from the link. But I'll wait to see what Narusan has to say and consider adding more then.

Comment: *Nerves are cut destined for the heart*. Without further explanation for OP, this seems the opposite of what they meant (*nerves destined for the brain*). I think the nerves OP wants to cut are those responsible for Angina pectoris. (As @BrianKrause pointed out). Now, I‘m unsure whether those nerves are part of the symphaticus and the ganglia that are to cut.

Comment: @Narusan I think you need to ask a new question. This is way beyond what was asked.

Comment: @CareyGregory OP asked for a treatment that cuts the nerves from heart to brain. You provided a treatment that cuts nerves from brain to heart (simplified greatly). I don’t quite see how this answered the question, and I think it would be best if you could elaborate. Because unless pain is also transmitted via the dissected ganglias, your answer wasn’t what OP wanted.

Comment: @Narusan I could be wrong but I don't think OP's understanding of neurological anatomy is good enough to distinguish such nuances and you're reading a lot more into the question than is there. Further, I don't think there is another procedure that meets the criteria **you** are looking for. I'm not spending more time on this answer. You can vote as you see fit, ask another question, or provide your own answer.